# Етимологія фразеологізму "зігнутися в три погибелі"

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

І в СУМ, і на інших ресурсах можна знайти значення фразеологізму **зігнутися/зігнутий в три погибелі**:

> ♦ [**Зігнутий (зогнутий, зігнений, зігнута і т. ін.) в три погибелі (в
> три дуги, вдвоє і т. ін.)**](http://sum.in.ua/s/zighnutyj) — дуже низько нахилений (нахилена і т.
> ін.). *Йому на думку спала зігнута в три погибелі постать Чижика
> (Панас Мирний, I, 1949, 256); Зігнений вдвоє Кирило перелазив через
> квітники (Мирослав Ірчан, II, 1958, 36)*.
>
> [**В три погибелі перегнутися (згинатися)**](https://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2311-v-try-pogybeli.html) в ролі прис.– дуже перегнути своє тіло, скорчитися.
> *Улесливий служник в три погибелі перегнувся: – Ваше вовче!.. Може, дозволите в вашу горлянку бистро­крилого орла запхнути? (Ковінька,
> Кутя з медом, 1960, стор. 66); Стомлений, я заснув, але швидко
> прокинувся від холоду. Мене всього пробирали дрижаки, я не міг
> нагрітися, хоч згинався в три погибелі (Багмут, За­писки солдата,
> 1961, стор. 31).*

Але не можу зрозуміти, чому саме **погибель**, чим пояснюється вживання саме цього слова, чи яке походження усього фразеологізму.

Серед значень іменника [**погибель**](http://sum.in.ua/s/poghybelj) у СУМ не бачу застосовних.

Щодо схожих за значенням фразеологізмів **зігнутися в три дуги**, **зігнутися в баранячий ріг** є навіть суто асоціативне розуміння.

Тож буду вдячна за джерела, що пояснюють етимологію фразеологізму **зігнутися/зігнутий в три погибелі**

Answer (score 4):

- За однією з версій слова *гинути* й *гнути* споріднені. Хоча *гинути* зазвичай виводять від праслов'янського *[*gynǫti](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/gyn%C7%ABti)* = *[*gybnǫti](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/gybn%C7%ABti)*, а *гнути* — від праслов'янського *[*gъbnǫti](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/g%D1%8Abn%C7%ABti)* = *[*gъnǫti](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/g%D1%8An%C7%ABti)*, але Рік Дерксен [вважає](//en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/g%D1%8Abn%C7%ABti&oldid=53594424#cite_ref-1), що вони обидва від праіндоєвропейського **gʰubʰ-*, а Макс Фасмер узагалі [каже](//lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/%D0%B3/%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C), мовляв, «праслов'янські *gyb- „гибнуть“ і *gyb- „гнуть“ етимологічно одноцілі». Відповідно, за цією версію виходить, що «зігнутий у три погибелі» початково означало «зігнутий у три згини» (можливо, у переносному значенні «дуже сильно зігнутий»). Таку версію висловлюють зокрема [в аналонічному запитанні на сайті «Русский язык»](//rus.stackexchange.com/a/18842) (щоправда без джерел) і [в підрозділі про крилаті вислови на сайті «uCoz fun»](http://fun.ucoz.ru/news/2000-11-11-82) (неавторитетно). Порівняти з «зігнутий у три дуги».
- Не виключаю також, що *погибель* тут може означати й буквально *загибель*. Мовляв, коли людина помирає через поранення в живіт, то вона може зігнутися, схопившись за поранене місце, відповідно, зігнутий у три погибелі — зігнутий так, як згинається перед смертю людина, поранена в живіт. Опосередковано про щось подібне кажуть [в підрозділі про крилаті вислови на сайті «uCoz fun»](http://fun.ucoz.ru/news/2000-11-11-82) (неавторитетно).

Comment: цікаві версії, дякую!